# Mysql compare comma-separated field with single string

Tags: mysql, comparison

So a field called schools in the database might have a value of:

```
'13,121,112,1212'
```

I'm using that to show the potential for a mistake.

Suppose I'm looking for a value of `12` in that field.  The commas denote a "whole number" and I don't want to match 112 or 1212

Is there a more elegant match than this?

```
@compare = 12;
WHERE CONCAT(schools,',') LIKE CONCAT('%',compare,',%)
```

I was recently impressed by the GROUP_CONCAT function but this is kind of in reverse of that.  Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(@compare, school) >0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this simple case you can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set);

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('13', schools);
```

Note though that there is no good indexing for columns with comma separated text, so the queries will be *much* slower than a normalized database.